# Why is ffmpeg_g slightly bigger than ffmpeg with --disable-debug?

Tags: ffmpeg, configure

When I compiled FFmpeg with --disable-debug, ffmpeg_g (22.2 MiB) was slightly bigger than ffmpeg (20.9 MiB), Why?

Comment: Presence of debug symbols,

Comment: @Gyan but --disable-debug disables debug symbols

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler optimizations are lost during the stripping process and ffmpeg compiles with -O3 by default.

Thanks to [Prem](https://superuser.com/users/281816/prem) for answering this question in the [Prem and me chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139939/discussion-between-therandomguynamedjoe12-and-prem).

Note that [Prem](https://superuser.com/users/281816/prem) didn't tell me about it defaulting to -O3

Comment: Checking here https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100748/0612/using-common-compiler-options/selecting-optimization-options :::: "Optimization level -O3" ... profitable to inline a call site increases .... amount of loop unrolling :::: Might be similar in other Compilers too.

Answer (score 1):

When you **"Enable Debug"** , the compiler will generate object code which is easy to put through Debuggers like `gdb` & hence it will not make major changes.

When you **"Disable Debug"** , the compiler will try to make the object code optimised , which includes `function inlining` & `loop unrolling` which will make the object code **"larger but faster"**.
That is what you are observing.

Comment: This answer dosen't explain why ffmpeg_g is slightly bigger than ffmpeg

Comment: What is "ffmpeg_g" ? The normal "ffmpeg" , but without Debug ? Then this is the Answer.

Comment: ffmpeg_g includes debug symbols normally but with --disable-debug it does not and ffmpeg never contains debug symbols

Comment: What is it used for ?

Comment: normally it's used for more precise gdb output but with --disable-debug idk

Comment: Size is Different because , after removing Debugging Symbols , the "final" version is optimised , that is "function inlining" & "loop unrolling" & etc. That will make it larger. Check whether you can compile with "no optimization" which will execute slowly or with "optimize for Size" which will execute more slowly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139939/discussion-between-therandomguynamedjoe12-and-prem).

Comment: TL;DR ffmpeg_g has debug symbols while ffmpeg does not opposing to what @Prem presumed